# Typescript module path resolution not working for .js files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, alias

I have a React project that I want to start migrating the js files to typescript. The aliases that's set up works if I import .tsx inside another .tsx file but doesn't work if I try to import .js files inside the .tsx file.

```
// inside app.tsx
import Main from 'Components/main'; // works if main is a .tsx file but not .js
```

I get this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Components/main'

It works if I do ./components/main.js but I want to use aliases.

webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            Components: path.resolve(__dirname, '/app/components/'),
    },
},
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.ts|.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,

    },
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                'thread-loader',
                { loader: 'babel-loader'}
            ],
        },
    },
//... other loaders
]
```

...

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
        "App": ["app"],
        "Components/*": ["app/components/*"],
    }
},
"include": [
    "./app/"
],
"exclude": [
    "./node_modules/"
]}
```

It would be great if I can use typescript path alias with js files. I set the allowJS to true inside the tsconfig.json but still no good.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using two loaders for Typescript files in webpack.

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        'thread-loader',
        { loader: 'babel-loader'}
    ],
},
{
    test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'thread-loader',
        },
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                happyPackMode: true,
            }
        },
    ],
},
```